# Koh Ribon - what connection does it have to Shabbos?

Tags: shabbat, song-poetry, shabbat-songs

One of the songs that is sung Friday night is Koh Ribon. There is not a single mention of Shabbos in it. Why do we sing it on Shabbos?

Answer (score 4):

There is not a single mention of Shabbos in Koh Ribon...

...or Tzur Mishelo, or Kel Adon, or the special Kedushas on Shabbat morning, or the extra psalms in P'sukei D'zimra, or the deluxe version of taking out the Torah.

Shabbos is just a very special day!  It has the special mitzvot of *Kavod* and *Oneg*.  Not everything has to announce its connection to Shabbos.  Just spending a little more time eating, davening, and singing is also an honor and a pleasure.

Comment: Fair enough, except that, re "the extra psalms in P'sukei D'zimra", we do say _Mizmor shir l'yom hashabas_.

Comment: @msh210, yes, but at least in Nusach Ashkenaz, we say it on weekday yomtovs too, so I figured I would include it.

Answer (score 3):

It speaks of the created world and praising HaShem for it 
i.e. G-d the Master of all Worlds, You are the Ruler, above all rulers. Your mighty deeds and wonders, it is beautiful​ to declare before You. 
I will sing Your praises in the morning and the evenings, to You Holy G-d Who created every soul, the angels above, all people, and the beasts that roam the grounds and the birds of the sky. Translation from [here](http://www.hibba.org/node/396) where there is a catchy recording.

Comment: Why the downvote? Other than the fact that it's exactly what I meant, so it's sort of duplicate, though more specific, I see no reason for someone to downvote this answer.

Comment: @SethJ, I downvoted, as it doesn't answer the question: it says what the song's about and translates part of it, but doesn't explain what _Shabas_ has to do with it, which is what the question asked.

Answer (score 3):

What is Shabbat if not the proclamation that Gd is the Master of the world?

Answer (score -1):

I'm gonna just guess - Zecher LeMa'aseh Bereishith/Zecher LiYtziath Mitzrayim. Sorry I don't have the freedom to look up sources on this at work.

Comment: What does "_Kah ribon_" have to do with _y'tzias Mitzrayim_?

Comment: "Master of the universe." He is All Powerful. Anyway, it was just a guess.